# Docker Apache with HTTPS Redirect

Tags: docker, apache, redirect, https

I have a Docker Container that is running Apache and everything is working just fine with the following Apache Conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName server.com
   ServerAlias www.server.com
   DocumentRoot /volume/site/default
   <Directory "/volume/site/default">
      Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
   </Directory>
   <IfModule mpm_user_module>
      ServerEnvironment apache apache
   </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName server.com
   ServerAlias www.server.com
   DocumentRoot /volume/site/default
   <Directory "/volume/site/default">
      Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
   </Directory>
   <IfModule mpm_user_module>
      ServerEnvironment apache apache
   </IfModule>
   SSLProxyEngine on
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /volume/certfile.pem
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /volume/certkeyfile.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

I can access the Docker Apache using the Docker Ports (set up as 801 and 4431)

```
http://server.com:801
https://server.com:4431
```

But I was wondering if it is possible to use an HTTPS Redirect to keep it on the HTTPS Port

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName server.com
   ServerAlias www.server.com
   DocumentRoot /volume/site/default
   Redirect permanent / https://server.com:443  # this doesn't work
   Redirect permanent / https://server.com:4431 # this also doesn't work
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName server.com
   ServerAlias www.server.com
   DocumentRoot /volume/site/default
   <Directory "/volume/site/default">
      Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
   </Directory>
   <IfModule mpm_user_module>
      ServerEnvironment apache apache
   </IfModule>
   SSLProxyEngine on
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /volume/certfile.pem
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /volume/certkeyfile.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

The HTTPS url is still accessible with this conf but the HTTP url becomes broken and I think I am misunderstanding how the redirect is resolving.

Going to `https://server.com:4431` stays working

Going to `http://server.com:801` goes to `https://server.com` and I'm not sure why

*UPDATE*

Just to note, if I do the exact same setup on a different server then everything works as expected, I think there may be another issue on this specific server that is causing this and it might not be related to the Apache Conf. I'm happy for this question to be closed but thank you to everyone for the help

Comment: What exactly happens when you access the http:// URL? To what do you get redirected (or do you receive some sort of error response)?

Comment: When I access `http://server.com:801` it redirects to `https://server.com`, I should include this in the question

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. If I deploy your configuration (using the second `Redirect` statement, because the first doesn't make any sense given your configuration), access on port 801 results in a redirect to `https://server.com:4431`.

Comment: @larsks if I do the exact same setup on a different server then everything works as expected, I think there may be another issue on this specific server that is causing this

Comment: Could something else be listening on the port to which you're trying to connect? Do you see the request on port 801 showing up in your Apache access log?

Comment: @larsks I don't see anything running on the ports except for 80 and 22 but I have limited access rights to this server so I'm almost certain there's more hiding where I can't see